# Overlay of layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I think to do a overlay of layout, this is the code that I have now.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_search"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_search"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="@string/placeholder_search"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search"
                    android:background="@drawable/style_input"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSend"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_header" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/list_search"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/no_result"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="@string/no_result"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center"/>


                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/search_categorias"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_buttons_tall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/style_header">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/otherlayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="Other Layout" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_buttons_tall1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/style_header"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/otherlayout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="Other Layout 2" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_buttons_tall2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/style_header"">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/otherlayoutn"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="Other Layout N" />

            </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to overlay the next layouts after of the ID "@+id/text_search" with the rest, this list is the a search and show suggestions to users.

This list will overlay about others layouts that I define below, if the user want to make a search.

Are there some way easy of overlay? Or tutorial that can help me. I try to use RelativeLayout, but I didn't get to make it well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Relative Layout for this, but you need to specify the relations (thats why relative => relative to what)

means you have to set the postion of your +id/text_search relative to parent.
and also the elements which should do the overlayer have to be relative to parent.

todo so relative Layout uses layout properties like: below=(ID) toRightOf(ID) and so on.

you can start reading about it here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

but for the search you want todo, there is already a good advice howto it: so i recommend reading this article:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

and doing it right, like all the others apps do it, your customers will be satisfied then (don't need to learn something new )

Comment: Thanks, I've researched your links and I found the solution. I've used RelativeLayout.

Comment: I have a question about "RelativeLayout", this overlaps the rest but it is fixed. Why? Does "RelativeLayout" does not work "Scrollview"?, I think that this is obvious, because is relative the screen. Does this have any fix? Thank in advance.

Comment: should work if you put the relative layout as child of the scrollview, and linear layout as parent of scrollview (so switch between root and child of scrollview )